# Moving row from one sheet to another does not work with ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use the script below to move data from sheet (Invoice_Info) to (Invoice_Archive) when cell value ="Save"  in column 20 in sheet (Invoice_Archive) I put arrayformula in column 21.

The problem is:

- when the data is moved to sheet (Invoice_Archive) it's put at the end of sheet
- when I remove the ARRAYFORMULA the script works well

What should I do to work script with arrayformula?

```
function onEdit() {

 var sheetNameToWatch1 = "Invoice_Info";
 var columnNumberToWatch = 20;
 var valueToWatch = "Save";
 var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Invoice_Archive";
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

 if ( (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch1) && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {
 var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
 var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
 sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, 20).copyTo(targetRange, {contentsOnly:true});
 sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue is with getLastRow in the targetsheet. The arrayformula is causing the row to be wrong. Try gstting the last row of column a with data loke this:

```
function onEdit() {
 var sheetNameToWatch1 = "Invoice_Info";
 var columnNumberToWatch = 20;
 var valueToWatch = "Save";
 var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Invoice_Archive";
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
 if ( (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch1) && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {
   var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
   var Avals= targetSheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues()
   var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
   var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(Alast + 1, 1);
  sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, 20).copyTo(targetRange, {contentsOnly:true});
 sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
 }
}
```